# AJAX alternative of using jQuery form UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was using the jQuery form plugin to process form submission (found [here](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js)) on my page but now have to switch to using an purely jQuery AJAX based method (without using any the form plugin but I can use jQuery). What would be the best method of achieving this? I'm having difficulty translating it across. What would an ideal solution look like?

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 

$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:        '#result',  
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  
    success:       showResponse   
}; 

// bind to the form's submit event 

$('#booking').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
    }); 
});  

// pre-submit callback 

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    var queryString = $.param(formData); 
    // alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
}

// post-submit callback 

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    $('#last-step').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#result').html(responseText).fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's AJAX function for this directly and, you can pass object literals as parameters without using the form elements.

```
var params = {id : '1234'};
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url, // action attribute from form element 
  data: JSON.stringify(params),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json', 
  success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
  },
  error: errorFunc
});
```

[Documentation can be found here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `options` variable in only one request you can create it directly in the `ajaxSubmit` function.

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
    target: '#result',
    beforeSubmit: showRequest, 
    success: showResponse
});
```

I think this way is more clear since you dont need to know what the variable `options` contains.

Other hint would be **be careful** with HTML DOM ids, they cannot be duplicated. In your case the use of HTML DOM classes would grant more stable code. (although HTML DOM ids have a better performance)